# Как прописать смену мак-адреса при перезагрузке для Mac OS

Tags: mac, macbook

Подскажите решение конкретно для Mac OS Sierra 
, находил много решений для Ubuntu и других ос, но они не работают

Answer (score 1):

Помог следующий код, прописал в applescript, сохранил, сменил права на 777 и добавил в автозагрузку пользователя:

```
  set newMac to "12:34:56:78:9A:BC"
  set psswrd to "pass"

  do shell script "ifconfig en0" & " ether " & newMac password psswrd with administrator privileges
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте вот эту команду `sudo ifconfig en0\eth0 (wi-fi\LAN) ether 01:23:45:67:89:0A (новый MAC)`, потом надо это добавить в автозагрузку в максимальным приоритетом